# Having some issu with cocos2d scoring system

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make scoring system in cocs2d but i am having some problem in the score , I have written these in .m

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bug.boundingBox, location)) {
        [self removeChild:bug cleanup: YES];
        score += 1;
        NSLog(@"%i", score);
    }
```

and I have declare score in the .h

```
@interface GameScene : CCLayer {
        NSMutableArray *bugs;
        int score;
```

}

but if I touch the sprite I get 1 score and the sprite get remove , but when i touch the place that the sprite where there I get +1 score every time i touch there .

I hope you understand .. thanks ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source code is less. However, you can use integer variable that will be declared in interface. In implementation set integer variable to 0 (in init method), and when you create new bug increase integer value to one more and set bug sprite tag to integer value like this:

```
// Interface
@interface yourScene:CCLayer {
    int bugsCount; // add new variable for counting current bugs
}

// implementation
@implementation
-(id) init {   

    if( (self=[super init])) {

        // Your code in init

        // integer value for counting current bugs
        bugsCount = 0;

    }

    return self;
}

-(void) addNewBug {

    // your code of adding bugs
    CCSprite *bug = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bug.png"];
    bugsCount++;
    bug.tag = bugsCount; // Your bug sprite tag should be equal current bugsCount value
    bug.position = ccp(x,y);
    [self addChild:bug];

}
```

in ccTouchEnded method just do for loop to detect which bugs is selected like this way:

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(id)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]]; 
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    location = [self convertToNodeSpace:location];

    // Detecting bug by touch
    for (i=1; i <= bugsCount; i++) {

        // get bug sprite by tag (from bugsCount idea)
        CCNode *bug = [self getChuldByTag:i];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(bug.boundingBox, location)) {

            // add new score (now this will work)
            score += 1;
            NSLog(@"%i", score);

            // remove bug from scene
            [self removeChildByTag:1 cleanup:YES];

            // decrease number of bugs
            bugsCount--;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the bug from the bugs array after you remove it from the scene graph, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach that should work for you (could of course be more efficient, but I decided to keep it simple)

Create a class called Bug with some properties in it, among them for example a BOOL called 'killed' that you set to true whenever a bug is killed. Let the bug have a reference to a sprite, or extend the sprite class so you can know where it is and if it is touched.

Now, when you press a bug, always check if it is killed, and if it is, don't award score for it.

Add all your bugs-objects to your bugsarray, instead of your sprites. You can access the sprites through the bugs-objects. When your bugs are killed, reuse them to save memory (i.e. move them away from the screen and let them appear again later, setting the "killed" property to false again)

Happy bug-hunting!